# Hoover, dust and iron

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She would hoover, dust and iron, but she didn't like doing windows.

I would like to look at expressing the point of the sentence in more simple words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are words referring to housecleaning.

- To *Hoover* is to vacuum.  (It is a brand name of vacuum cleaner.)
- To *dust* means to clean away dust, typically with a cloth.
- To *iron* is to make cloth (as in clothes or sheets) flat and wrinkle-free, by passing a hot *iron* over it.
- To *do windows* means to clean windows.

(And I'm sure you could have found each of these words in a dictionary, instead of asking here...)

Comment: Thank you. I thought "do window" means construct a new window and therefore I couldn't understand the point of the sentence correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> She would clean the house, but she didn't like cleaning windows.

"Hoover" is very British, it is not used in other countries.

> Do the windows / laundry / dishes / taxes

never means to build new. This sentence form means any common but complicated task that is understood by almost everyone. Washing your clothes requires at least 9 steps, not including the machine stages, but we all know what they are. 100 years ago laundry required an entire day's work for your wife, eldest daughter and the maid.